# How to create a TypeScript 5 property decorator?

Tags: typescript

I have the following decorator:

```js
const bound = (method: any): PropertyDecorator =>
    ((target: any, name?: PropertyKey): any => {
      if(name === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Bound decorator must be used with a property name.');
      }

      return {
        get(): any {
          return target[method].bind(this);
        }
      };
    });

class Foo {

  @bound('bar')
  foo!: any;


  bar(): string {
    return 'bar';
  }

}
```

and I want to convert it to a TypeScript 5 decorator. This was my attempt:

```js
const bound = (<
    This,
    Value
>(method: keyof This): any => ((
    _value: undefined,
    context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<This, Value>
) => {
  if(context.private) {
    throw new Error('Bound decorator cannot be used on private properties.');
  }

  context.addInitializer(function(this: This) {
    (this as any)[method] = (this[method] as CallableFunction).bind(this);
  });
}));
```

Here's the JS output for the decorator:

```js
const o = (i) => (n, r) => {
  if (r.private)
    throw new Error("Bound decorator cannot be used on private properties.");
  r.addInitializer(function() {
    this[i] = this[i].bind(this);
  });
};
export {
  o as bound
};
```

At runtime, I get `TypeError: context.addInitializer is not a function`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my config:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictBindCallApply": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node10",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "target": "es2017",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "composite": true,
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "outDir": "./dist"
    },
    "files": [
        "./src/bound.ts",
        "./src/index.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./node_modules",
        "./dist"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates the runtime error? How are you applying it to a property? I don't see the problem if I copy your code into the TS Playground, so presumably the answer to your question depends on information you haven't presented here.

Comment: @jcalz Added. It's a pretty standard decorator a lot of people use, so didn't think a minimal, reproducible example would do it justice.

Comment: I think "reproducible" is the key word here, and we still haven't gotten that (at least I can't get what you've provided to cause a problem in my runtime).  What compiler configs are you using?  What's the full runtime output?  When you use TS5 decorators you should get a whole bunch of helper stuff with it... what's actually calling your decorator at runtime?

Comment: Are you sure you're using TypeScript 5? It's a silly question, but sometimes silly questions are worth being asked

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Yup, 5.1.6

Comment: Are you making ESDecorators(TS5) or experimentalDecorators(TS4)?

Comment: Trying to make an ES decorator.

Comment: I should mention that I am building with Vite.

Comment: Could you provide the *full* runtime output?  If you look at [the JS output at this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6VERw) you can see that it's huge and includes all kinds of stuff to support decorators, since not even ESNext supports ES Decorators yet. Does your JS output *not* include those?

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina @jcalz You're right, it's odd that my output is different than that of playground. I added my config (given by `--showConfig`) to the post.

Comment: And just in case, I ran `tsc --version` and got 5.1.6.

Comment: So I realized that if you remove the usage of the decorator, the JS looks more like mine. So, I guess TS doesn't generate everything without a usage. But I am trying to put this in a library with no usages. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: ① In that tsconfig, why are `--experimentalDecorators` and `--emitDecoratorMetadata` enabled? That's [not using ES Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#differences-with-experimental-legacy-decorators) ② It's only when decorators are used that those things matter. You'd only get the `context.addInitializer is not a function` error if it were being used, so what is the code that uses the decorator? What output is *that* generating? Presumably that is TS also, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can implement in ES decorators (TS5+)
https://tsplay.dev/wO2azW

```
function bindField<B extends string>(method: B) {
    return function <T extends Record<B, T[K] & Function>, K extends keyof T>(
        value: undefined,
        context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<T, T[K]> & {
            name: K;
            private: false;
            static: false;
        }
    ): (this: T, value: T[K]) => T[K] {
        return function inializer(this: T, value: T[K]): T[K] {
            return this[method].bind(this)
        }
    }
}

class Foo {
    @bindField('bar')
    foo!: this['bar']

    bar(): string {
        return 'bar';
    }
}

console.log(new Foo().foo())
```

Comment: TS2339 on the call to `bind`.

Comment: @Oliver works fine for me https://tsplay.dev/wO2azW